# setState isn't re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm learning React through [this](https://youtu.be/CWEOYFzgOJs) tutorial on Youtube.

I've looked through many answers but I can't find a similar case. I don't think I'm mutating data since the filter method in BlogList.jsx does return a filtered array, and I'm passing that newly created array to setState. (in this case, `setBlogs`)

Home.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import BlogList from './BlogList';
import { blogData } from '../data';


function Home() {

    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(blogData);

    function handleDelete(id) {

        const newBlogs = blogs.filter((blog) => blog.id !== id);
        setBlogs(newBlogs);

        console.log(blogs);
        console.log(newBlogs);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <BlogList blogs={blogData} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

BlogList.jsx

```
function BlogList({ blogs, handleDelete }) {
    
    return (
        <div className="blog-list">
            {blogs.map((blog) => (
                <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                    <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                    <p>Written by {blog.author}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(blog.id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default BlogList;
```

data.js

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

// blog initial data.
const blogData = [
    {
        title: "Master HTML",
        body: "lorem ipsum...",
        author: "umaru-chan",
        id: uuidv4(),
    },
    {
        title: "CSS Is Hard!",
        body: "lorem ipsum...",
        author: "ebina-chan",
        id: uuidv4(),
    },
    {
        title: "JavaScript makes no sense",
        body: "lorem ipsum...",
        author: "kubo-san",
        id: uuidv4(),
    },
];

export { blogData };
```

Comment: Now I know my question is rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in home.jsx you pass blogData to BlogList while setBlogs change blogs state not blogData

```
<BlogList blogs={blogData} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
```

change to :

```
<BlogList blogs={blogs} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
```